# PHP, __get() method, and array parameter

Tags: php

I want to achieve this effect:

```
class Foo {
   public $bar; // array('aaa' => array('bbb' => 'ccc'))
   public function __get($value)
   {
      return $this->bar[...][key($value)]; // don't know what to implement here
   }
}

$obj = new Foo();
$obj->aaa['bbb']; // should return 'ccc'
```

Is this possible? How can I do this?

How can I get to the 'ccc' value from the Foo::$bar array from the inside of the __get() method if I want to call it this way?

Comment: Please post your actual code and no `[...]` parts. So someone will be able to help you.

Comment: edited, hope it looks clearer now.

Comment: Why would `$obj->aaa['bbb']` return `ccc`?

Comment: According to the deleted post: var_dump($obj->bar['aaa'][1]);...Exactly, can this be $obj->aaa[1]?

Comment: He's trying to convert each array member into an object, it looks like.

Comment: @khernik I still see `$this->bar[...][key($value)]`!

Comment: your `$value` would equal `aaa` ... you seem to be expecting that it would equal `bbb` in your example.

Comment: @khernik do you mean `array('aaa' => array('bbb' => 'ccc'))` instead of `array('bbb', 'ccc')`

Comment: Crap, yes, thanks, I didn't see that !

Comment: Editet, it should look clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $bar = array('aaa' => array('bbb' => 'ccc'));
    public function __get($value) {
        return $this->bar[$value];
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
echo $obj->aaa['bbb'];
```

will return:

```
ccc
```

Comment: Well, this returns array('bbb' => 'ccc'). Somehow, echoing $value inside of the __get() method returns only the "aaa", not the 
"aaa['bbb']".

Comment: @khernik Of cause because this `echo $obj->aaa['bbb'];` is `echo $obj->__get('aaa')['bbb'];` and will return your array.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {
   public $bar = array('aaa' => array('bbb' => 'ccc'));
   public function __get($value)
   {
      return $this->bar[$value];
   }
}

$obj = new Foo();
var_dump($obj->aaa['bbb']);
```

Got what you wanted after your edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class Foo 
{
    // note you had: array('aaa' => array('bbb', 'ccc'));
    // so `bbb` and `ccc` were values, not keys.
    public $bar = array('aaa' => array('bbb' => 'ccc'));

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->bar[$name];
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
echo $obj->aaa['bbb']; // should return 'ccc'

// output: ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from how you phrased the question, but I think this might be what you're looking for?

```
<? 
class Foo {
    function __construct(){
        $bar = array(
            'aaa' => array('bbb' => 'ccc'),
            'zzz' => array('yyy' => 'xxx'),
        );
        foreach($bar as $key => $value){
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
    public function __get($value){
        // return $this->bar[...][key($value)]; // don't know what to implement here
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
echo $obj->aaa['bbb']; // ccc
echo $obj->zzz['yyy']; // xxx
```